# issue in imageloading using picasso

Tags: android, picasso

i have one spinner.when i set the image in spinner.load image not proper .so what happend some image looks small,some image not show,when i scroll down or up some image not show.sometime what happened in loading image takes time

SpinnerAdapterRecharge.java

```
public class SpinnerAdapterRecharge extends ArrayAdapter<listview_data> {
    private Activity context;
    listview_data data[] = null;
    int layoutResourceId;

    public SpinnerAdapterRecharge(Activity context, int resource,listview_data[] data)
    {
        super(context, resource, data);
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        this.layoutResourceId = resource;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        return getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {   // This view starts when we click the spinner.
        View row = convertView;
        listHolder holder = null;
        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new listHolder();
            holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.spinnerimageIcon);
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.spinnerOperator);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (listHolder)row.getTag();
        }
        listview_data item = data[position];

        if(position == 0)
        {
            holder.imgIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.txtTitle.setText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.lbl_operator));
        }
        else {
                Picasso.with(context)
                        .load(item.icon)
                        .resize(30, 30)
                        .error(R.drawable.imagenotavailable)
                        .into(holder.imgIcon);

                    holder.txtTitle.setText(item.title);
        }

        return row;
    }
    static class listHolder
    {
        ImageView imgIcon;
        TextView txtTitle;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because Picasso loads it asynchronously.

Comment: please if possible , explain in details..and any other option

Comment: You're also setting `holder.imgIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE)`. There should be a `View.VISIBLE` in the `else` condition in case you receive a recycled view on a `postion >= 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of answering your question:

Right now Picasso loads the images asynchronously with this:

```
 Picasso.with(context)
                        .load(item.icon)
                        .resize(30, 30)
                        .error(R.drawable.imagenotavailable)
                        .into(holder.imgIcon);
```

If you want to have it synchronously, you can use the `get()` method of Picasso.

```
 Bitmap bitmap = Picasso.with(context)
                        .load(item.icon)
                        .resize(30, 30)
                        .error(R.drawable.imagenotavailable)
                        .get();
 someImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

---

Here is maybe a better solution from another SO answer.

```
/**
 * Loads the request into an imageview.
 * If called from a background thread, the request will be performed synchronously.
 * @param requestCreator A request creator
 * @param imageView The target imageview
 * @param callback a Picasso callback
 */
public static void into(RequestCreator requestCreator, ImageView imageView, Callback callback) {
  boolean mainThread = Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper();
  if (mainThread) {
    requestCreator.into(imageView, callback);
  } else {
    try {
      Bitmap bitmap = requestCreator.get();
      imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
      if (callback != null) {
        callback.onSuccess();
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      if (callback != null) {
        callback.onError();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Source: [Synchronous image loading on a background thread with Picasso - without .get()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27239203/synchronous-image-loading-on-a-background-thread-with-picasso-without-get)

---

Basically, that is the gist of synchronous loading.

Comment: hey i used your code.but there is error display in get() method